# Meteor rest api with iron router

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a rest api running on my meteor app with reststop2. This project is now depreciated stating:

> Everything that this package is capable of can now be accomplished
>   using iron-router server-side routes and core Meteor packages (for
>   example accounts-password).

With some help from [rest-api](https://github.com/awatson1978/rest-api/tree/master/client) I have got end points up and running but I am having difficulties with authentication. The statement above suggests to use accounts-password but i cant see any methods that I can use on the server, they are all for the client.

I have also tried to use:

```
Accounts._checkPassword(user, password);
```

but I get the error TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iron-router has middleware options built-in, where you can do authentication for your REST API: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/examples/middleware/middleware.js

In this function, you can validate your user and throw an error if it's not valid credentials.

I don't know if this is helpful, but I'm authenticating my users using Google accesstokens. Here's my code (in coffeescript):

```
getUserByToken: (token) ->
    getUserByEmail getEmailByToken token

getEmailByToken: (token) ->
    getUserInfo(token)?.email

getUserInfo: (token) ->
    try
        oauthUser = HTTP.get 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + token
    catch error
        console.log 'error authenticating', error
        null
    oauthUser?.data

getUserByEmail: (email) ->
    if email
        Meteor.users.findOne 'services.google.email': email
```

Answer (score 2):

I published a package for writing REST APIs in Meteor 0.9.0+ that supports authentication. It is meant to replace RestStop2 now that it is deprecated, and has a similar API:

https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus

It was inspired by [RestStop2](http://github.differential.com/reststop2/) and built with [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router)'s server-side routing.

**UPDATE:** I just wanted to include a code example for anyone that finds this. This is the Restivus Quick Start example from the [GitHub README](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus#restivus) (check out the README if you'd prefer the [sample code in JavaScript](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus#javascript)):

```
Items = new Mongo.Collection 'items'

if Meteor.isServer

  # API must be configured and built after startup!
  Meteor.startup ->

    # Global API configuration
    Restivus.configure
      useAuth: true
      prettyJson: true

    # Generates: GET, POST, DELETE on /api/items and GET, PUT, DELETE on
    # /api/items/:id for Items collection
    Restivus.addCollection Items

    # Generates: GET, POST on /api/users and GET, DELETE /api/users/:id for
    # Meteor.users collection
    Restivus.addCollection Meteor.users,
      excludedEndpoints: ['deleteAll', 'put']
      routeOptions:
        authRequired: true
      endpoints:
        post:
          authRequired: false
        delete:
          roleRequired: 'admin'

    # Maps to: /api/posts/:id
    Restivus.addRoute 'posts/:id', authRequired: true,
      get: ->
        post = Posts.findOne @urlParams.id
        if post
          status: 'success', data: post
        else
          statusCode: 404
          body: status: 'fail', message: 'Post not found'
      post:
        roleRequired: ['author', 'admin']
        action: ->
          post = Posts.findOne @urlParams.id
          if post
            status: "success", data: post
          else
            statusCode: 400
            body: status: "fail", message: "Unable to add post"
      delete:
        roleRequired: 'admin'
        action: ->
          if Posts.remove @urlParams.id
            status: "success", data: message: "Item removed"
          else
            statusCode: 404
            body: status: "fail", message: "Item not found"
```